# Cannot pull data between view controllers: Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a view controller with a name input text box in it. I want to be able to pull the name.text value from my main view controller, but I'm struggling with the code.

Sorry, I know there are similar questions, I am struggling to understand where I am going wrong though, here is my code:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     if segue.identifier == "statsegue" {

        let statVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController

        NameLabelMain.text = statVC.NameDisplayStat.text

       //or try that if above doesn't work: detailsVC.passedString = recipes[indexPath?row]
    }
}
```

This is on my main page, trying to pull the data from my second view.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common timing problem.

In `prepareForSegue` the view of the destination view controller is not loaded yet so all `IBOutlet`s are not connected yet (aka not available).

You can only access data which is available right after initialization.

However generally you are passing data from the source controller to the destination controller rather than the other way round.

Comment: Ah! That explains a lot, thanks. I don't suppose you have any advice on a better way to handle this?

Comment: If you really want to *pull* data then you could use a callback closure, in case to *push* data you need to declare a temporary variable and update the UI element of the destination controller in its `viewDidLoad()` method.